# Как сделать запись слова в ячейку массива string

Tags: c++, массивы

возникла задача записывать слово word в рандомный массив slovo1 slovo2 или slovo3 типа string. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой, что, если все слова будут идти по порядку в один массив, то все работает, а ,если массивы будут чередоваться, то некоторые ячейки массивов будут пропускать и запись не будет осуществляться по порядку. Как можно записывать переменную `word` в свою ячейку массивов слов по порядку,попробовал через switch, но столкнулся с проблемой, описанной выше.

Может следует использовать вместо switch другой метод? Подскажите,пожалуйста как правильней будет поступить?

```
  #include <iostream>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string>
    #include "alphabet.h"
    #define size 13
    using namespace std;


    string Alphabet() {
        string alphabet;
        cout << "Введите 6 букв вашего алфавита: " << endl;  cin >> alphabet;
        return alphabet;
    }


    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        setlocale(0, "RU");
        srand(time(NULL));
        string alphabet= Alphabet();
        string slovo1[size], slovo2[size], slovo3[size];

        int wordsCount = 9 + rand() % 4;  // Случайное количество слов
        for (int i = 0; i < wordsCount; ++i)
        {
            int wordLength = 5 + rand() % 10;  // Случайная длина слова
            string word;
            for (int j = 0; j < wordLength; ++j)
                word += alphabet[rand() % alphabet.length()];
            int randomCategory = rand() % 3 + 1;
            switch (randomCategory)
            {
            case 1:
                slovo1[i] = word;
                break;
            case 2:
                slovo2[i] = word;
                break;
            case 3:
                slovo3[i] = word;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            cout << word << endl;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Поддерживайте три индекса - для каждого массива - и будет вам счастье :) Только вот в каждый массив могут быть записаны разное количество слов!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поддерживайте три индекса - для каждого массива - и будет вам счастье :)

```
int wordsCount = 9 + rand() % 4;  // Случайное количество слов
int i1 = 0, i2 = 0, i3 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < wordsCount; ++i)
{

....

        case 1:
            slovo1[i1++] = word;
            break;
        case 2:
            slovo2[i2++] = word;
            break;
        case 3:
            slovo3[i3++] = word;
            break;
```

Еще варианты - матрица слов (массив из трех массивов), тогда можно обойтись без `switch`, а еще лучше - векторы строк. Тогда автоматически решается  проблема, что в каждый массив могут быть записаны разное количество слов...

Comment: Спасибо,но я еще не совсем понимаю про векторы строк,поэтому пока доступными средствами пытаюсь все делать,но спасибо еще раз за подсказку,почитаю про векторы строк